# Change vehicle target method

Tags: veins, sumo

I created a method `changeTarget` in the *TraCICommandInterface.cc* file where I used the `chageTarget` TraCI command to change the destination. I want to know whether it is a correct implementation or not and also if the `nodeId` mentioned in the method is the same as the `nodeId` of *TraCICommandInterface.h*. So can I use the `nodeId` or do I need to use the `getexternalId()` method to get the vehicle id?

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::changeTarget(std::string roadId) {
    uint8_t variableId = CMD_CHANGETARGET;
    uint8_t variableType = TYPE_COMPOUND;
    uint8_t edgeIdT = TYPE_STRING;
    std::string edgeId = roadId;
    TraCIBuffer buf = connection->query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << variableType << edgeId<<edgeIdT);
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The type should always go in front of the value and you don't need a compound here. So something like the following:

```
uint8_t variableId = CMD_CHANGETARGET;
uint8_t edgeIdT = TYPE_STRING;
TraCIBuffer buf = connection->query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << edgeIdT << roadId);
```